# Write Json string manually using LibGDX library

Tags: json, gwt, libgdx

LibGDX implements JSON readers and writers.
This allows your to compile for GWT (org.json.JSONobject does not have a GWT implementation).
It is great to serialize objects and to instantiate objects from Json strings.
In my case I wanted to generate the JSON without starting from an object/class.

Having read through the documentation (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reading-&-writing-JSON)  I could not find a good example and I struggled a little to get it working.  So I publish here how I got it done in the end (maybe there is a better, cleaner way to achieve the same result).

Answer (score 1):

So to manually produce a JSON String that would look like this using LibGDX Json library:

```
{
  "name":"BOB",
  "surname":"DAVID",
  "phones":[
    { 
      "mobile":,"xxx-x-x"
    },
    {
     "landline":,"xxx-x-x"
    }
  ]
}
```

You could use that kind of code which I have dumbbed down for illustration purpose:

```
public String harcodedLIBGDXJSON(){
        Json jsonObject = new Json();
        StringWriter jsonText = new StringWriter();
        JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(jsonText);
        jsonObject.setOutputType(JsonWriter.OutputType.json);
        jsonObject.setWriter(writer);
        jsonObject.writeObjectStart();
        jsonObject.writeValue("name", "BOB");
        jsonObject.writeValue("surname","DAVID");
        jsonObject.writeArrayStart("phones");
            {
                Json aPhoneNumber = new Json();
                aPhoneNumber.setOutputType(JsonWriter.OutputType.json);
                aPhoneNumber.setWriter(writer);
                aPhoneNumber.writeObjectStart();
                aPhoneNumber.writeValue("mobile", 'xxx-x-x');
                aPhoneNumber.writeObjectEnd();

                Json aPhoneNumber = new Json();
                aPhoneNumber.setOutputType(JsonWriter.OutputType.json);
                aPhoneNumber.setWriter(writer);
                aPhoneNumber.writeObjectStart();
                aPhoneNumber.writeValue("landline", 'xxx-x-x');
                aPhoneNumber.writeObjectEnd();
           }

        }

        jsonObject.writeArrayEnd();
        jsonObject.writeObjectEnd();
        return jsonObject.getWriter().getWriter().toString();
    }
```

note: If you don't use 'object.setOutputType(JsonWriter.OutputType.json);' it will use by default minimal annotation (so for example it won't use double quotes around your strings which caused me some issues in other part of the code).